# Multiplication using pi notation problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

$$
\prod _{n=4}^{\infty}\frac{(n^3+2n)^2}{(n^2-4)(n^4+2n^2+9)}
$$
I am not understanding this question.I think the measure is decreasing while $n$ is increasing. So it will be $0$ at last. But that isn't a mathematical solution. That's just a logical solution. So I need a correct process. If this term converges to $1$, then please give me the solution.

Comment: The term converges to $1$.

Comment: The Limit this sequence, when  $n$ tend to infinity is $1$ not is $0$

Comment: A subtle feature of this problem is $n^4+2n^2+9$ sneakily factors.  Render $(n^4+6n^2+9)-4n^2=(n^2+2n+3)(n^2-2n+3)$.

Comment: [Wolfram|alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product+%28n%5E3%2B2n%29%5E2%2F%28%28n%5E2-4%29%28n%5E4%2B2n%5E2%2B9%29%29%2C+n%3D4+to+infinity) gives the approximate result of $5.44816$

Answer (score 2):

To understand the growth rate, it suffices to look at the leading terms. In the numerator, you have $(n^3+\cdots)^2=n^6+\cdots$. In the denominator, you have $(n^2+\cdots)(n^4+\cdots)=n^6+\cdots$. Since these degrees are the same, the limit of the term is the ratio of their coefficients, i.e. $1/1=1$.

As an aside, note that the term converging to one is *necessary but insufficient* to conclude the product converges; this mirrors the case with series. However, we can show the product converges by using the result that for a positive sequence $(a_n)$, $\prod_n (1+a_n)$ converges if and only if $\sum_n a_n$ converges. In our case, we have $a_n \approx 48/11 n^{-2}$, so the product will converge.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}\\
\prod _{n=4}^{\infty}\frac{(n^3+2n)^2}{(n^2-4)(n^4+2n^2+9)}
&=\prod _{n=4}^{\infty}\frac{n^6 + 4 n^4 + 4 n^2}{n^6 - 2 n^4 + n^2 - 36}\\
&=\prod _{n=4}^{\infty}(1+\frac{6 n^4 + 3 n^2+36}{n^6 - 2 n^4 + n^2 - 36}\\
\end{array}
$

and since
$\sum _{n=4}^{\infty}\frac{6 n^4 + 3 n^2+36}{n^6 - 2 n^4 + n^2 - 36}
$
converges,
the product converges
to a positive value.

Going further,
interesting things happen.

$\begin{array}\\
p(m)
&=\prod _{n=4}^{m}\dfrac{(n^3+2n)^2}{(n^2-4)(n^4+2n^2+9)}\\
&=\prod _{n=4}^{m}\dfrac{n^2(n^2+2)^2}{(n-2)(n+2)(n^2+2n+3)(n^2-2n+3)}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod _{n=4}^{m}n^2}{\prod _{n=4}^{m}(n-2)\prod _{n=4}^{m}(n+2)}\prod _{n=4}^{m}\dfrac{(n^2+2)^2}{((n+1)^2+2)((n-1)^2+2)}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod _{n=4}^{m}n\prod _{n=4}^{m}n}{\prod _{n=2}^{m-2}(n)\prod _{n=6}^{m+2}(n)}
\dfrac{\prod _{n=4}^{m}(n^2+2)^2}{\prod _{n=4}^{m}((n+1)^2+2)\prod _{n=4}^{m}((n-1)^2+2)}\\
&=\dfrac{(m-1)m\cdot 4 \cdot 5}{2\cdot 3(m+1)(m+2)}
\dfrac{\prod _{n=4}^{m}(n^2+2)\prod _{n=4}^{m}(n^2+2)}{\prod _{n=5}^{m+1}(n^2+2)\prod _{n=3}^{m-1}(n^2+2)}\\
&=\dfrac{20(m-1)m}{6(m+1)(m+2)}
\dfrac{(4^2+2)(m^2+2)}{((m+1)^2+2)(3^2+2)}\\
&=\dfrac{20\cdot 18(m-1)m(m^2+2)}{6\cdot 11(m+1)(m+2)((m+1)^2+2)}\\
&=\dfrac{60(m-1)m(m^2+2)}{11(m+1)(m+2)((m+1)^2+2)}\\
&\to \dfrac{60}{11}\\
\end{array}
$

Note:
according to Wolfy,
$\dfrac{(m-1)m(m^2+2)}{(m+1)(m+2)((m+1)^2+2)}
=1-6/m + 21/m^2 - 54/m^3 + 111/m^4 + O((1/m)^5)
$.